# Error in the results of a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a issue with list comprehensions.

```
import numpy
import random

diam=1.5
p=1
a=10
d=0.2
h=0.15

lx = list(numpy.arange(-diam/2,diam/2+0.05,0.05))

for loop in range(50):
    f=random.uniform(0,p/2)

    l = [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a)<-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a))] + [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a))>(d/2)]
```

But when I look at the results, there seems to be some errors.
For `a=10`, for the last value of `f`,

```
l = [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133]
```

Then if I type this

```
[k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a) for k in     list(np.arange(-diam/2,diam/2+0.05,0.05))]
```

I get this

```
[-0.72926117723233752, -0.68565303028301938, -0.64160406588192997, -0.59711428402906952, -0.54781631527556185, -0.49318773203196459, -0.43899996624013848, -0.38525301790008354, -0.33194688701179981, -0.27908157357528718, -0.22665707759054576, -0.17467339905757551, -0.12313053797637638, -0.072028494346948441, -0.021367268169291655, 0.028853140556593968, 0.07863273183070843, 0.12797150565305171, 0.17686946202362386, 0.22532660094242482, 0.27334292240945463, 0.32091842642471324, 0.36805311298820076, 0.41474698209991706, 0.4610000337598622, 0.50681226796803625, 0.55218368472443902, 0.60288571597093177, 0.65839593411807129, 0.71434696971698208, 0.77073882276766403]
```

(I'll refer to it as `mylist`)

And I know that `-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a) = -0.12644904710626975` and `d/2 = 0.1`

Then if I look at the values in `mylist`, I notice that the 12 first values are inferior to `-0.12644904710626975`.
However, in `l`,  there are only 11 consecutive values for `k` (`-0.15` should be in `l` too).

I don't understand why `-0.15` isn't in the list `l`.

EDIT : Here's another sample

`l = [-0.75, -0.7 , -0.65, -0.6 , -0.55, -0.5 , -0.45, -0.4 , -0.35,
       -0.3 , -0.25,  0.1 ,  0.15,  0.2 ,  0.25,  0.3 ,  0.35,  0.4 ,
        0.45,  0.5 ,  0.55,  0.6 ,  0.65,  0.7 ,  0.75]`

`mylist = [-0.73693754824886837, -0.68054569519818642, -0.62459465959927574, -0.5690844414521361, -0.51401504075676774, -0.45938645751317042, -0.40519869172134437, -0.35145174338128943, -0.29814561249300564, -0.24528029905649307, -0.19285580307175165, -0.14087212453878137, -0.089329263457582256, -0.038227219828154309, 0.012434006349502473, 0.06265441507538809, 0.11243400634950255, 0.16177278017184585, 0.21067073654241797, 0.25912787546121896, 0.30714419692824874, 0.35471970094350741, 0.40185438750699487, 0.44854825661871117, 0.49480130827865632, 0.54061354248683036, 0.58598495924323313, 0.63091555854786485, 0.67540534040072531, 0.7194543048018146, 0.76306245175113285]`

The 12 first values of `mylist` are inferior to `-0.12644904710626975`, but in `l`, there are only 11 consecutive values : `-0.2` should be in `l` too.

(Verification : `k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a)` for `k = -0.2`, and we get `-0.1408721245387819` which is inferior to `-0.12644904710626975`)

Comment: -0.19999999999999951 looks very much like -0.2 to me, with rounding errors

Comment: Yes, of course, it was a mistake, I meant -0.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the way i checked - it seems good. Could You provide different sample, i'd  be happy to look into it.

```
import numpy as np
import random

diam = 1.5
p = 1
a = 10
d = 0.2
h = 0.15

lx = list(np.arange(-diam/2, diam/2 + 0.05, 0.05))

for loop in range(50):
    f = random.uniform(0, p/2)
    a1 = [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a)<-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a))] + [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a))>(d/2)]
    a2 = [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a)<-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a))]
    a3 = [k for k in lx if (k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a))>(d/2)]
    a4 = [k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a) for k in list(np.arange(-diam/2,diam/2+0.05,0.05))]

print "lx", lx
print "a1", a1
print "a2", a2
print "a3", a3
print "a4", a4

# however...
print -d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a)
print k+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(k**2)))*np.tan(a)
print -0.19999999999999951 < -d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a)
print -0.14999999999999947 < -d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a)


# EDIT2 => addition, see explanation below.

print "EDIT 2 results step by step equation from comment below answer"
print "==========================================="
x1 = (1/(2*p))
print "x1 = ", x1
x2 = (0.05**2)
print "x2 = ", x2
print "abs(f-x1*x2) = ", abs(f-x1*x2)
print "np.tan(a) = ", np.tan(a)
print "abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a) = ", abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a)
print "abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a) + 0.05 = ", 0.05 + abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a)
print "==========================================="
```

output

```
lx [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, -0.14999999999999947, -0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133]
a1 [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133]
a2 [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951]
a3 [0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133]
a4 [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, -0.14999999999999947, -0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133]
-0.197254124119
0.75
True
False
EDIT 2 results step by step equation from comment below answer
===========================================
x1 =  0
x2 =  0.0025
abs(f-x1*x2) =  0.0
np.tan(a) =  0.648360827459
abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a) =  0.0
abs(f-x1*x2) * np.tan(a) + 0.05 =  0.05
===========================================
```

---

EDIT, in response to @Jack's comment and post edit.

@Jack - sample You provided in edit is still unclear. But first: a4 and lx values are the same, feel free to copy this post to new script and test it Yourself. Are You sure that values in Your post are correct? You refer to 0.12644904710626975, while my example clearly states that:

```
-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a) != -0.12644904710626975
-d/2-h/np.tan(np.pi/2-a) == -0.197254124119
```

Perhaps You changed d/h/a somewhere else in Your program.
How about You assign some variables in place of such long constructs like these, they are hard to read and may cause errors.
I don't also know, what are parameters You used to generate values in Your edit.
Perhaps You could write what are You trying to achieve, it might be easier to fix problem this way.

---

EDIT2:

In Your comments below You wrote:

> a4 and lx are not the same, I just tried and I get lx = [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, (...)
>   whereas a4 = [-0.67386015491279805, -0.64736323490818992, -0.61924541283493406, -0.58950668869303047, -0.54185293751752051, -0.47483346579671942, (...)
>   The value seems to be -0.197254124119. Sorry, I probably mixed different values... Anyway, for d/2 = 0.1, you can see that the last 15 values of mylist in the EDIT example are superior to 0.1, but there are only 14 consecutive values for the last values of l
>   And 0.05+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(0.05**2)))*np.tan(a) = 0.15540118660134225 > 0.1. So why 0.05 isn't in the list l ?

Have you copied above script and tried it on Your computer, exactly as it is written? I have added above another few rows starting and ending with "==========", to demonstrate step by step results I'm getting from calculations. Please note that diam, p, a, d, h are NOT changed anywhere. Below I've written cause - why that is happening and what can You do to avoid such behavior.

## SUMMARY

Now we actually see what has happened. Please observe what value x1 has got. We have x1 == 0 whereas we (as a human beings) clearly see that 1/(2*1) is 0.5.
You probably know why this is happening, but in case You don't, computers dont count as us - it is called integer division in Python2 (it has changed in Python3, `2/2 = 1.0`), so in Python2 "normal" division operator "/" dividies integers, whereas "//" divides float's. Some other ways are also possible, casting one of operands to float before division like this `float(1)/2  == 0.5` or, using statement `from __future__ import division`. I'm pretty sure that You can also write Your number straight as a float like this `1.0/2 == 0.5` so it means that there are at least four ways of getting proper result.

In summary, You need to use one of these four ways in Python2:
- `1//other_number`
- `1.0/other_number`
- `float(1/other_number)`
- use normal "/" with `from __future__ import division` statement in front of Your script.

---

EDIT3: turns out, OP is using Python3

```
import numpy as np
import random

diam = 1.5
p = 1
a = 10
d = 0.2
h = 0.15

lx = list(np.arange(-diam/2, diam/2 + 0.05, 0.05))
# Are You aware that casting numpy array to list You loose precision?
# compare:
# print(np.arange(-diam/2, diam/2 + 0.05, 0.05))
# print(list(np.arange(-diam/2, diam/2 + 0.05, 0.05)))

# constants
x1 = 1/(2*p)
tan = np.tan(a)
cond1 = -d/2 - h/np.tan(np.pi/2 - a)
cond2 = d/2
disp1 = "abs( f - x1 * k**2 ) * tan = {} \n(f was {}, last k was {})\n"

print("cond1 = {}".format(cond1))
print("cond2 = {}".format(cond2))
print("")

for loop in range(1):

    f = random.uniform(0, p/2)
    a1 = [k for k in lx if k + abs(f - x1 * k**2 ) * tan < cond1]
    a2 = [k for k in lx if k + abs(f - x1 * k**2 ) * tan > cond2]
    a = a1 + a2
    b = [k + abs(f - x1 * k**2 ) * tan for k in lx]

    last  = abs(f - x1 * lx[-1]**2) * tan
    print(disp1.format(last, f, lx[-1]))
    print("a1=", a1, "\n")
    print("a2=", a2, "\n")
    print("lx=", lx, "\n")
    print("a=", a, "\n")
    print("b=", b, "\n")

    # we have: 
    # lx with uniform distribution from 0.75 to 0.75 with step 0.05
    # a1 which will have values from lx up to condition
    # a2 will have rest of lx's values
    # effectively a which is sum of a1 and a2 should be equal lx
    # in rare cases where condition is equal to cond1 or 2, should not.
    # and we have b where i suppose You were testing what Your condition
    # does.
    # So looking at lx[i] and a[i], while checking b[i] versus cond1 or cond2
    # We could see what You intended.
```

output (Python3):

```
cond1 = -0.197254124118863
cond2 = 0.1

abs( f - x1 * k**2 ) * tan = 0.0266300386512908 
(f was 0.32232286795171455, last k was 0.7500000000000013)

a1= [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969] 

a2= [-0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133] 

lx= [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, -0.14999999999999947, -0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133] 

a= [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, 0.50000000000000111, 0.55000000000000115, 0.6000000000000012, 0.65000000000000124, 0.70000000000000129, 0.75000000000000133] 

b= [-0.72336996134870857, -0.64986688135331661, -0.57798470342657238, -0.50772342756847588, -0.43908305377902707, -0.37206358205822598, -0.30666501240607263, -0.24288734482256696, -0.18073057930770905, -0.12019471586149885, -0.061279754483936383, -0.0039856951750216196, 0.05168746206524541, 0.10573971723686473, 0.15817107033983635, 0.20898152137416023, 0.25817107033983638, 0.30573971723686488, 0.35168746206524559, 0.39601430482497857, 0.43872024551606381, 0.47980528413850143, 0.51926942069229121, 0.55711265517743336, 0.59333498759392778, 0.62793641794177446, 0.66091694622097341, 0.69227657243152474, 0.72201529657342822, 0.75013311864668408, 0.7766300386512921]
```

I assume You are aware that `f` gets random value each time in this for loop, and that You essentially create arrays a and b 50 times for different f's, but only last is accessible, since You dont store them. Perhaps You wanted to append element to list in this range?

Ad rem, judging by what You are trying to do it boils down to selecting items from lx that fulfil cond1 < item < cond2, whereas there may be multiple better solutions for how to do that, let's check Yours.

If we observe above, b[i] where i=0...n we see that in this example 8 first values fulfil first condition, (being smaller than -0.197...), so list a1 is populated with first eight numbers from lx.
Next, five consecutive numbers from b[i] does not match any condition, and a2 starts from index 14 (or 13 if counting from 0), so everything is correct. a is populated with first 8 items from lx and next from remaining items starting from index 13.
Even in Your first example with -0.12... all numbers from lx that fulfiled condition were in L.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added another sample in my original post, after EDIT (I didn't have enough space in the comment).

Comment: However, `lx` and `a4` can't be the same list.

Comment: a4 and lx are not the same, I just tried and I get
`lx = [-0.75, -0.69999999999999996, -0.64999999999999991, -0.59999999999999987, -0.54999999999999982, -0.49999999999999978, -0.44999999999999973, -0.39999999999999969, -0.34999999999999964, -0.2999999999999996, -0.24999999999999956, -0.19999999999999951, -0.14999999999999947, -0.099999999999999423, -0.049999999999999378, 6.6613381477509392e-16, 0.050000000000000711, 0.10000000000000075, 0.1500000000000008, 0.20000000000000084, 0.25000000000000089, 0.30000000000000093, 0.35000000000000098, 0.40000000000000102, 0.45000000000000107, ...`

Comment: whereas
`a4 = [-0.67386015491279805, -0.64736323490818992, -0.61924541283493406, -0.58950668869303047, -0.54185293751752051, -0.47483346579671942, -0.40943489614456607, -0.3456572285610604, -0.28350046304620252, -0.22296459959999232, -0.16404963822242982, -0.10675557891351507, -0.05108242167324803, 0.0029698334983712937, 0.055401186601342897, 0.10621163763566678, 0.15540118660134294, 0.20296983349837139, 0.2489175783267521, 0.29324442108648507, 0.33595036177757043, 0.37703540040000794, 0.41649953695379782, 0.45434277143893992, 0.49056510385543434, 0.52516653420328108, ...`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but what do you mean by "assign some variables" ?

Comment: The value seems to be `-0.197254124119`.
Sorry, I probably mixed different values...

Anyway, for  `d/2 = 0.1`, you can see that the last 15 values of  `mylist` in the EDIT example are superior to 0.1, but there are only 14 consecutive values for the last values of `l`.

Comment: And `0.05+(abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(0.05**2)))*np.tan(a) = 0.15540118660134225 > 0.1`.
So why `0.05` isn't in the list `l` ?

Comment: by assign some variables i mean, split Your calculations into some smaller parts - to avoid mistakes. for example, lets assign b1 = abs(f-(1/(2*p))*(0.05**2)) => (probably better naming could be used, by You), and we have easy to read 0.05+b1*np.tan(a) - why this is important ? To spot otherwise difficult mistakes regarding brackets and so on. This way You can avoid mixing up different values, and it will be easier to spot where is actual mistake.

Comment: I'll make another edit ==> i've checked Your example from comment above...and again got different result. (Please see edited answer). Are you sure You didn't modify array before/after? Is this script Your whole program, or do You access this array somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Actually, I'm not using Python 2 but Python 3.
So when I type `(1/2*p)`, I get `0.5` and not `0`.

I think that's why we are getting different results.
Could you check the results with Python 3 please ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I finally spotted the mistake, it was later in my code, but thanks to you I am sure that this part of my code is correct